# apache alias pages that load relative resources

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I am trying to alias a path to a specific file

I tried:

```
Alias /Console "/console/console.html"
```

Now going to `http://example.com/Console` indeed brings `console.html`.

but any relative resource referenced from within `console.html` (ie, `images\1.jpg`) fails as it seems to go to the document_root

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should work if you do a redirect instead of an alias.

Comment: ok but isn't redirect much slower, as in the client have to issue the request again ? isn't there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a client-side problem related to your use of relative URLs. Since you are effectively rewriting the URL from `/console/console.html` to `/Console`, any relative URL (to images, CSS, JS, etc.) are now going to be relative to the document root and not the `/console` subdirectory.

You need to either "fix" your relative URLs and make them root-relative (ie. starting with a slash, as in `/console/images/1.jpg`) or make them absolute.

Alternatively, you can include a `base` element in the `head` section of your HTML document. This references the absolute URL that all relative URLs are *relative* to. In other words, since you are expecting these relative URLs to be relative to the `/console/console.html` document then add the following to the `head` section:

```
<base href="http://example.com/console/console.html">
```

Now, a relative URL such as `images/1.jpg` referenced in a document at URL `/Console` will request `http://example.com/console/images/1.jpg`, not `http://example.com/images/1.jpg`.

However, there are caveats with using the `base` element. Notably, if you have in-page relative links using fragment identifiers, eg `href="#some-id"`. This is also now relative to your `base` element so the in-page link may now be broken. The only way round this is to fully qualify the link.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

---

However, `Alias` is not the correct directive to use when mapping to a single file, since `Alias` is prefix matching, so `/Console/foo` would map to `/console/console.html/foo` as well. You could perhaps use `AliasMatch` instead:

```
AliasMatch ^/Console$ /console/console.html
```

This will map only `/Console`.

Or, you could use mod_rewrite instead and issue an *internal rewrite*. (As opposed to an *external redirect* that would otherwise change the URL and cause the client to issue a second request.) For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?Console$ /console/console.html [L]
```

Comment: tanks ! base tag is apparently not so trustworthy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag

Comment: and making my urls root relative is not an option, so I think I'll have to go for an external redirect