# Redirect but load from another folder

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, url

I'm useing this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/exampelFile exampelFile.php?data=$1 [L]
```

and my problem is that the page dosn't load my css&js file.
It seems the php page it self is getting loaded form

```
www.example.com/some text/exampelFile...
```

insted of

```
www.example.com/exampelFile?data=some text...
```

and this why it dosn't find the css&js files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache alias pages that load relative resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/835292/apache-alias-pages-that-load-relative-resources)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your rewrite rule only does internal rewriting and doesn't redirect the browser to that URL. Therefore the browser is still on page `www.example.com/some_text/exampelFile`; all the relative links and locations in the HTML of your `exampelFile.php` are relative to that location, not to the actual file location, as they are obtained by the browser.

You could prevent this by making it a redirect with [`RewriteRule`'s](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) flag `R`:

> `'redirect|R [=code]'` (force redirect)
>
> Prefix Substitution with
>   `http://thishost[:thisport]/` (which makes the new URL a URI) to force a
>   external redirection. If no code is given, a HTTP response of `302`
>   (MOVED TEMPORARILY) will be returned.

Resulting:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/exampelFile /exampelFile.php?data=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: after putting this flag it send me to 404 Error

Comment: On what location? Before or after the redirection? Is there something on that location?

Comment: when I redirect with R flag, so it send me to he actual link `http://example.com/exampelFile?data=some_text` but I want it to overide the URL, so the presented URL in the URL toolbar `http://example.com/some text/exampelFile` (thats the hol point in useing htaccess so the pressented link will be more elegant..

Comment: If you change the directive to an external redirect (ie. `R=3xx`) then you'll need to make the _substitution_ root-relative or absolute, otherwise the directory-prefix will be added back (in `.htaccess`) and break the redirect. Unless of course the `RewriteBase` has already been set, then you don't need to.